# NSIS : How to keep input value from previous dialog after click Next/Back button?

Tags: textbox, dialog, nsis

If I change value in textbox and click Next button, then click Back button to back to the page again, I wanna keep new value that I changed it in textbox. How can I do?

This is my code :

## AcustomPage.nsh

```
!macro create_AcustomPage APP_NAME CUS_FULLNAME
Page custom create_AcustomPage leave_AcustomPage
Function create_AcustomPage
        Push $0
        StrCpy $AcustomPage.FirstOpened 0
        nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $AcustomPage
        GetDlgItem $AcustomPage.Button.Next $HWNDPARENT 1
        System::Call user32::GetWindowText(i$AcustomPage.Button.Next,t.s,i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})
        nsDialogs::CreateControl STATIC ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_CLIPSIBLINGS} 0 0u 0u 100% 20u "${AcustomPage_TITLE}"
        Pop $AcustomPage.Text
        ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 0u 20u 100% 78% "AcustomPage Setting"
        Pop $AcustomPage.SettingBox

        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10u 50u 20u 11u "URL:"
        Pop $AcustomPage.FULLNAME.Label
        ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u ""
        Pop $0
        ${NSD_OnChange} $0 Update_AcustomPage_Next_Button
        ${If} ${CUS_FULLNAME} != ""
            ${NSD_SetText} $0 ${CUS_FULLNAME}
        ${EndIf}
            
        Call Update_AcustomPage_Next_Button
        nsDialogs::Show
    FunctionEnd
    
    Function leave_AcustomPage
        ${NSD_GetText} $0 $CUS_FULLNAME
    FunctionEnd
    
    Function Update_AcustomPage_Next_Button
    Push $R5
        ${NSD_GetText} $0 $R5
        ${If} $R5 != ""
                    EnableWindow $AcustomPage.Button.Next 1
                    Return
        ${EndIf}
        ${If} $R5 == ""
            EnableWindow $AcustomPage.Button.Next 0
            Return
        ${EndIf}
    Pop $R5
    FunctionEnd
!macroend
```

Thanks,

Comment: Update_AcustomPage_Next_Button is calling Return and will never Pop so you are corrupting the stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by always saving the text in $CUS_FULLNAME in the leave callback but you never use $CUS_FULLNAME to set the text when creating the page, you seem to try to do something with ${CUS_FULLNAME} instead!

It should probably look more like this:

```
${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${CUS_FULLNAME}"
Pop $0
${If} $CUS_FULLNAME != ""
  ${NSD_SetText} $0 $CUS_FULLNAME
${EndIf}
${NSD_OnChange} $0 Update_AcustomPage_Next_Button
```

Here is a standalone example:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

var hCtlFullName
var FullName

Function mypageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 60u 30u 60% 11u "$FullName"
Pop $hCtlFullName
${NSD_OnChange} $hCtlFullName mypage_VerifyInput

call mypage_VerifyInput
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function mypageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $hCtlFullName $FullName
FunctionEnd

Function mypage_VerifyInput
Call mypageLeave ; Loads the text into $FullName
Push $0
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
${If} $FullName == ""
    EnableWindow $0 0
${Else}
    EnableWindow $0 1
${EndIf}
Pop $0
FunctionEnd

Page Custom mypageCreate mypageLeave
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section
DetailPrint $FullName
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders, but I'd like to know how different between using
`${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${CUS_FULLNAME}"`
and
`${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "$CUS_FULLNAME"`
And what it should be?

As my code as above, macro had two parameters, how can i use them correctly. Because I tried changed as your suggest and added Pop also, but it still the same (It does not store value).

I'm really sorry if my question were basically, but I'm really new about NSIS. Thank you very much for an example & explain.